# how to prove $(2/3)^n < 1/n$ easily?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I cant find an easy way to solve this, can you help?

$(2/3)^n < 1/n$

$n$ is natural and district $(1,2,3...)$

I tried using induction and basic algebra.

Comment: Induction is a good way to go. What stopped you?

Comment: $(3/2)^n > n$ is a little more obvious.

Comment: What is $n$ is natural and *district*?Do you mean *distinct*?

Comment: @tatan it means it can only get separated values (1,2,3..)

Comment: @YardenST That's called **distinct**...

Comment: You could take the limit of the ratio of successive terms to show that the LHS decreases faster.

Comment: @tatan 'Discrete'?

Comment: yea you should write it discrete, it was a typo

Answer (score 5):

Induction works. The cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ are obvious. Assume that $\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^n < \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in \mathbf N_{>2}$. Then by the induction hypothesis
$$\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^{n+1}= \left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^n  \left(\frac{2}{3} \right) < \frac{2}{3n}  < \frac{1}{n+1}. $$
(The last inequality is equal to $2(n+1)<3n$ which is fulfilled because we assume $n>2$.)

Comment: You only need one $<$, given by the induction hypothesis. The other $<$ can be $\le$ and you can take $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 3):

By the Bernoulli inequality,
$$
\left(1+\frac12\right)^n\ge 1+\frac12n.
$$
As $\dfrac94>2$, ameliorate this for $n>2$ via
$$
\left(\frac32\right)^n=\frac94\left(\frac32\right)^{n-2}\ge \frac94\left(1+\frac12(n-2)\right)=\frac98n>n.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:-

$$(\frac{2}{3})^n<\frac1n$$

$$\implies\frac{2^n}{3^n}<\frac1n$$

$$\implies n<(1.5)^n$$

and $n\in\mathbb N$.

Hence,the result follows.

Comment: why it follows now? n<(3/2)^n might looks right but isn't a proof

Comment: @YardenST Now use induction....it will be easier...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to LutzL's binomial answer, if $n\ge2$, then

$$\left(3\over2\right)^n=\left(1+{1\over2}\right)^n\ge1+{n\over2}+{n(n-1)\over8}={n^2+3n+8\over8}\gt n$$

The final inequality follows from

$$(n^2+3n+8)-8n=n^2-5n+8={4n^2-20n+32\over4}={(2n-5)^2+7\over4}\gt0$$

Answer (score 1):

On the LHS to go from one term to the next you multiply by 2/3. On the RHS to go from one term to the next you multiply by n/(n+1). The multiplicand on the RHS is greater than the multiplicand on the LHS for n greater than 2. Thus LHS decreases faster than RHS. It is also easily verified that LHS is less than RHS for some n. This is sufficient.